# Jumping ball physics in java, gravity

Tags: java, animation, sprite, game-physics

I've made a simple code to get jumping ball positions, but I definitely missed something, because I get this: [image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2guxibn.png]

Here's the code for getting x and y positions:

```
public Vector2f[] draw() {
    float x = 0, y = height; // height - float value from class constructor;
    ArrayList<Vector2f> graphic = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
    for(;;){
        Vector2f a = new Vector2f(x, y);
        graphic.add(a);
        ySpeed -= 10;
        y += ySpeed*Math.cos(angle);
        x += xSpeed*Math.sin(angle);
        if(y <= 0){
            // float coef = -10 * y / ySpeed;
            // ySpeed = ((ySpeed + coef) * (-1) ) * bouncyness;
            ySpeed = (ySpeed * (-1)) * bouncyness;
            System.out.println(ySpeed + " " + y);
            y = 0;
        }
        if(x > Main.width)
            break;
    }
    Vector2f[] graphicArray = new Vector2f[graphic.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < graphic.size(); i++) {
        graphicArray[i] = graphic.get(i);
    }
    return graphicArray;
}
```

Comment: Two remarks: 1) Better use `List<Vector2f> graphic` and 2) is there a reason for `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`?

Comment: At last i solved this problem! with your help, of course :) I deleted `y = 0`, and then i set `ySpeed` inside the `if` block to `(ySpeed * (-1) + 10) * bouncyness;` and it worked! Here's the final piece of code if someone is interested:

Comment: `for(;;){  
                Vector2f a = new Vector2f(x, y);  
                graphic.add(a);  
                ySpeed -= 10;  
                y += ySpeed;  
                x += xSpeed;  
                if(y <= 0){  
                    ySpeed = (ySpeed * (-1)+ 10) * bouncyness;  
                    System.out.println(ySpeed + " " + y);  
                }  
                if(x > Main.width)  
                    break;  
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On its iteration `y` gets lower than the X axis on the first run. Then being zeroed,
So max `height` that you will get in that iteration is lower than original `height`.
The same happens later,
Until `y` will get to 0 without being set to it ( I think it will always converge to it ).
If you will set your `height` to be divided by `10` it should look alright.

For the bouncing case change `if ( y <= 0)` to `if ( y<= 10 )` and remove `y = 0` statement.
The correct situation ( not bouncing ), set `y = Math.abs(y)`

Comment: Now i'm setting `y` to `Math.abs(y)` in the `if` block but smth is still wrong: http://i60.tinypic.com/2dbl94n.png

Comment: @Fa2m, OK, try `y=10 + y` instead

Comment: Now waves look like some kind of weird stairs //
i mean every time the max height of the next wave is lower then the max height of the previous wave

Comment: @Fa2m Can you show it? Also add where the angle is computed.

Comment: @Fa2m Try to change the `if` block to `if (y <= 10)` and don't set `y` at all

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts

- I don't have a clue what you are doing with the `angle`. To me, it looks plain wrong. Try to get rid of it.
- You should integrate the acceleration twice over one timestep to make it work physically correct.

  ```
  x += v + acc * ∆time * ∆time * 0.5;
  v += acc * ∆time;
  ```
- Make `y = -y` when y < 0.

Where your `∆time` is `1` and your `acc` is `-10`, I guess.

Comment: With `y = -y` i'm getting almost same graph as in this screenshot from the previous answer =( : http://i60.tinypic.com/2dbl94n.jpg // UPD: I mean, same answer, because `y = -y` is equal to `y = Mathf.abs(y)` in this case

Comment: @Fa2m: Yes, I saw that. But try the formulas I gave you for the integration (note that the order is important). While still doing `y = -y`, off course.